# How to test method include async method in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, testing

I want to test method using async method.
But, when i run test, UnityEditor is blocking.

I think, this problem is because async method.
i don't know how to solve this problem.

Unity version : Unity 2020.3.33f1

```cs
public async static Task<string> GetAsync() {

    // Do something
    HttpResponseMessage response = await request.GetAsync(..);
    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


    return response Data
}

...


public string GetData() {
    Task<string> res = GetAsync();
    return res.Result;
}


////////////////// Test Code //////////////

[Test]
public void Test_GetData() {
   ...
   string res = GetData()
   ...
}
```

Comment: Make it async all the way. Your test methods can be asynchronous. `public async Task Test_GetDataAsync() { string res = await GetDAsync(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing it, you need to use async/await in all places.

When using async/await, as you have done Task for returning string type, but for void method, you just use Task.

let's say

```
public static async Task<string> GetAsync()
{
    return await Task.FromResult("test");
}
```

and your test should be like this:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test_GetAsync()
{
    var result = await GetAsync();
    Assert.AreEqual("test", result);
}
```

---

if we take your code so

```
public async static Task<string> GetAsync() {
    // what ever
    .....
    return responseData
}
```

the test will be:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test_GetData() {
   ...
   string res = await GetData()
   ...
}
```

---

If your test project is an older .net framework, you would level it up to a newer version as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475695/3088349) suggests. Otherwise, if you are locked and not able to upgrade, you can do something which I am not suggesting as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549641/async-await-vs-getawaiter-getresult-and-callback) mentions.

```
[Test]
public void Test_GetData()
{
    var result = GetAsync().GetAwaiter();
    Assert.AreEqual("test", result.GetResult());
}
```

Comment: The method I am testing is the GetData() method, which is not the async method. If you modify it in the way you recommended, the following error will occur.

```
'string' does not contain a definition of 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)
```
```

Comment: Check update answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My unity environment set .net version is 4.0. I will try more.